# Android View.post(Runnable) - Running but not affecting UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, view, viewgroup

I'm trying to add a view to the toolbar in my Android Activity.  The below "decorView" is a RelativeLayout child view of the actionbar/toolbar.

Defining the Container:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar == null) {
        Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    }

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setCustomView(getActionBarLayoutResourceId());
        this.mActionBarView = (RelativeLayout) actionBar.getCustomView()
                .findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_action_bar);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    } else {
        log("ActionBar is null");
    }
```

Adding the view:

```
final ViewGroup decorView = this.mActionBarView;

Runnable postDecorHeaderView = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (decorView.getWindowToken() != null) {
                // The Decor dView has a Window Token, so we can add the
                // HeaderView!
                decorView.addView(mHeaderView);
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log(e.getClass() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                }
                // The Decor View doesn't have a Window Token yet, post
                // ourselves again...
                decorView.post(this);
            }
        }
    };

    decorView.post(postDecorHeaderView);
```

I have verified that decorView's child count increases after this method completes.  Unfortunately, my "mHeaderView" does not show up, nor does it appear in view hierarchy analysis.  I have tried other UI updates like changing a TextView's text to no avail.

I have verified the identity of the decorView from within the runnable.  If I log the runnable, I see it running, I verify that it's running on the main UI thread... but no visual updates occur.

Comment: I ran a simple test and have no problem adding views to a parent container using post( Runnable ). Can you try decorView.invalidate() after adding the view?

Answer (score -1):

By grabbing the toolbar from the existing view, the custom layout was already present in the view.  So I did not need to additionally "setCustomView".  I'm not sure where this second custom view layout ended up on the screen (even using debug tools, I couldn't find the layout), but trying to post to and add a child view were not working.

Ultimately, all I did was change the mActionBarView setter to:

```
this.mActionBarView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_action_bar);
```